# Variable inside of the markup for an asp:HyperLink NavigationUrl property?

Tags: asp.net

I'm new to ASP.NET and can't figure out how to accomplish this...

My code (that needs fixing):

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server"
          NavigateUrl="~/EditReport.aspx?featureId=<%= featureId %>" />
```

featureId gets defined as an integer in the backing code.  I want href's like...

```
  /EditReport.aspx?featureId=2224
```

...but instead I am getting...

```
  /EditReport.aspx?featureId=<%= featureId %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without using the HyperLink control a bit easier:

```
<a href='<%=ResolveUrl("~/EditReport.aspx?featureId=" + featureId) %>'>Link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Most asp.net developers have run into this at one time or another.  This is my favorite solution as it works for any server control:

http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/09/The-CodeExpressionBuilder.aspx

Effectively you add this guy's brilliant little custom ASP.NET Expression Builder to your project, then rewrite the control to look like this:

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server"
     NavigateUrl='<%$ CODE: String.Format("~/EditReport.aspx?featureId={0}", featureId) %>' />
```

As he explains it's cleaner than the `<%# %>` method as there's no ViewState involved.  Note also the use of the single quotes which allow double quotes to be used inside the attribute.